# When is it possible to change the subnet group within AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have one Oracle SE instance that is not multi-az and does not have encryption enabled, and I have an Oracle EE instance that is multi-az and has encryption enabled. The former has the option to change the subnet group through the console (modify instance > network and security), whereas the latter does not. Both instances are in a subnet group within the default vpc, and I have a custom vpc within the same account with another subnet group in it.

What conditions determine whether or not it is possible to change the subnet group of an RDS instance? I have not been able to find any documentation on this so far.

Comment: Are you asking about subnet groups or security groups? Sorry. dumb question?

Comment: I'm talking about subnet groups.

Comment: Is the VPC and subnets in the same region as the databases? Do you have IAM permissions to edit that one?

Also there is nothing on the limitations page with encryption. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.Oracle.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html
The subnet group for the DB instance. You can use this setting to move your DB instance to a different VPC. If your DB instance is not in a VPC, you can use this setting to move your DB instance into a VPC.

Comment: I verified that I see the same behavior for mysql. Not sure what is the answer to your question though!

Comment: Re strongiz: I know how to change the subnet group when the setting is available, however there are cases when it is not. My question is why. I do not have any databases that are not in a VPC. Yes, everything is in the same region, and yes I have IAM permissions.

Comment: Re doles: What exactly is your setup, just for the sake of comparison?

Answer (score 6):

It is the Multi AZ Deployment that is the determining factor. To test this, modify your DB instance and turn off the Multi AZ Deployment. Once it is done, go modify it again and you'll notice you now have the option to change the subnet group.

I haven't found any indication as to the reason for this behavior in the AWS documentation.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that the Multi AZ is the determining factor. I converted rds to single az and the subnet modification appears.

But then, do you have any idea why we can only change to the subnet group in different VPC?

Comment: Documentation seems wrong. We cannot change subnet group without changing VPC. More detail https://serverfault.com/a/817598/556236

Answer (score 6):

#### My understanding

RDS instances can't be migrated from one database subnet group to another if:

- The destination database subnet group is in the same VPC as the current group
- The instance has the multi-availability zone setting enabled

#### What worked for me

1. Creating the subnet group within my VPC that would be the eventual home of my RDS instance
2. Creating a temporary database subnet group in the "DEFAULT" VPC (my RDS instance has previously been a subnet group in a VPC that I had provisioned, not the default one) consisting of the three subnets that belong to the "DEFAULT" VPC—this can be done in the RDS section of the AWS Console, no need to go to the VPC section
3. Modifying the instance's subnet group to the newly created group (from **2.**)
4. Modifying the instance's subnet group to its eventual home within my original VPC (from **1.**)

Answer (score 1):

As @hackakhan mentioned, you need to have Multi AZ Deployment turned off to modify the DB subnet group of an RDS instance. Unfortunately, the RDS instance will only be migrated to one of the subnets from the new DB subnet group if the new DB subnet group resides in a different VPC. You could create a temporary VPC to migrate away the RDS instance only to migrate it back to your existing VPC and the right DB subnet group within that VPC.

The AWS Premium Support Knowledge Center has a detailed explanation of the steps involved: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-vpc-rds-db-instance/

Comment: FYI: The VPC needs an Internet Gateway attached to it for this.