# RDS subnet group change error "Can't be on same VPC as RDS"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, subnet

I can't find documentation on this error, and when I do it doesn't really fix my issue.

> We're sorry, your request to modify DB instance  has failed. You
> cannot move DB instance  to subnet group <NEW GROUP. The specified
> DB subnet group and DB instance are in the same VPC. Choose a DB
> subnet group in different VPC than the specified DB instance and try
> again.

I have 1 VPC and two subnet groups 1 of subnet A, B, and C which are identical defaults in different zones. subnet group 2 is D, E, and F which are identical in different zones.

**Why am I getting an error about needing different VPC when the current subnet group is in the same VPC already?**

**Background**: I recently changed default subnet settings to point A, B, and C to a NAT gateway and created D, E, and F which point to an IGW. I did this so my lambda on the same VPC can access the internet, now I can't connect to my DB any longer...

https://serverfault.com/questions/816820/aws-can-not-change-db-subnet-group-for-aws-rds doesn't explain this error, it only states you can't switch subnet groups, but this error suggests I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html)) explains that you can only change subnet group when moving your DB to a different VPC:

> The subnet group for the DB instance. You can use this setting to move your DB instance to a **different VPC**.

> In the Network & Security section of the modify page, shown following, enter the new subnet group for Subnet group. The new subnet group **must be a subnet group in a new VPC**.

This explain why you are getting the error - changing subnet group withing same VPC is not supported.

The link you've provided explains workarounds, e.g. using snapshots or a temporary VPC.

Comment: thank you I didn't realize that this rule only applies when changing to a new VPC, this makes much more sense for the workaround answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a documentation from AWS with step by step of how to get this done.
Full page content [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-move-to-private-subnet).

**Short description**
Amazon RDS doesn't provide an option to change the subnet group of your DB instance within the same VPC. However, you can use the following workaround to move your DB instance from a public subnet to a private subnet. When you use this workaround, you don't need to create a new DB instance or use the snapshot-restore process. The workaround also minimizes downtime when you create a new instance and divert traffic. Only the failover time results in noticeable downtime.

Note: Use this workaround only for RDS DB instances. If your DB instance is part of an Aurora cluster, then use the clone option. Or, follow this resolution, but don't turn off Multi-AZ. Instead, delete and recreate the readers.

I hope this help.

Note: Sometimes you might need to move the instance to another vpc, you could just use the default vpc, and when the db is ready again, then you will be able to move it to the subnets in the vpc that you'd like. More steps also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259561/6456107).